# friend inline functions violates MISRA C 2012 Rule 8.10

Tags: c++, misra

Let's say we have the code snippet

```
#include <stdint.h>

class T {
    int32_t a;
    friend void foo(T*p);
};

inline void foo(T*p) {
    p->a = 1;
}
```

MISRA C checker will complain

> Type: MISRA C-2012 Declarations and Definitions (MISRA C-2012 Rule
> 8.10, Required)   Triage unavailable. main.cpp:8:
>
> 1. misra_c_2012_rule_8_10_violation: The inline function "foo(T *)" is not declared with a static scope.

But code like below is illegal

```
#include <stdint.h>

class T {
    int32_t a;
    friend static void foo(T*p); // error: storage class specifiers invalid in friend function declarations
};

static inline void foo(T*p) {
    p->a = 1;
}
```

How can we workaround it? Thank you.

Comment: Every lint like code checking tool has false positives. Every last one of them.  None of them are perfect. Fortunately, all of them come with macros use you can use to wrap the problematic code with.  A quick Google search reveals the available of various pragmas (including push/pop semantics) and comment structures you can use to disable a particular warning (or all warnings) from being fired during the scan.

Comment: You cannot run a MISRA C 2012 checker on a C++ program, simple as that. Voting to close as "simple typo" since this holds no value for future readers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> friend inline functions violates MISRA C 2012 Rule 8.10

No, they do not.

1. As it says right in the name, MISRA C applies to **C**.  Friend functions are a C++-specific feature addressing a C++-specific issue.  **C++ is not C**, and MISRA C does not apply to it.  Not once does MISRA C 2012 mention the C++ language.

   MISRA did release one set of C++ guidelines, MISRA C++ 2008, but it seems largely to have been abandoned. Whereas MISRA C received multiple amendments and technical corrigenda, and two revised editions (the latest retitled MISRA C2023), MISRA does not seem to have published any further work on C++ guidelines since 2008.
2. **The problem is not that a friend function is inline, but rather that an inline function is not static**.  That the function in question is a friend to some class is coincidental.  And this particular rule is aimed squarely at the C version of inline functions, which have some important differences from C++ inline functions.

I am uncertain how or why you are checking C++ code against MISRA C, but you should not.  MISRA C overall is not appropriate for C++, and those parts that are applicable to C++ are in no way sufficient to meet MISRA's safety goals.

> How can we workaround it?

***Option 1***: stop checking C++ code against rules devised for the C language.

***Option 2***: make the function an ordinary external function instead of an inline function.  If the inline version is presently defined in a header, then you would also need to move that definition to a regular source file:

**header.h**

```
#include <stdint.h>

void foo(T *p);

class T {
    int32_t a;
    friend void foo(T *p);
};
```

**source.cpp**

```
#include "header.h"

void foo(T *p) {
    p->a = 1;
}
```